# how to merge data frames generated in a while loop on a key

Tags: python, dataframe, while-loop, merge

I have a while loop, and a dataframe is generated each iteration.
I want to merge dataframes after every iteration on a key (let's say column `id`):

```
 while i < 600:
        try:
            player_html = urlopen("https://fantasy.premierleague.com/drf/element-summary/" + str(i))
            player_raw = json.load(player_html)
            fixture = player_raw['fixtures']
            data_df = pd.DataFrame(fixture)
            new_column = data_df.columns
            new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=new_column)
            new_df = new_df.merge(data_df, on='id')

        except:
            #Write all of the numbers for which there was errors to a file
            errfile = open(player_error, "a")
            errfile.write(str(i) + "\n")
            pass

        print (i)
        i += 1
    return new_df
```

This was my logic, but it is not working. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `data_df` should be the initial batch of df that any consequent `new_df` must be appended.

However, as it is **inside** the while loop, it's keep on getting reset.
That being said, assigning data_df before the loop should do the job.

```
 data = pandas.read_excel(*******)
 data_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

 while i < 600:
    try:
        new_column = data_df.columns
        new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=new_column)
        new_df = new_df.merge(data_df, on='id')

    except:
        #Write all of the numbers for which there was errors to a file
        errfile = open(player_error, "a")
        errfile.write(str(i) + "\n")
        pass

    print (i)
    i += 1
```

In addition,

- `pandas.read_excel` returns `DataFrame` so the second line could be redundant.
- Not sure how `pandas` is imported but if it was `import pandas as pd`, do use pd only (i.e. first line)

Comment: Actually I edited my question. Since I was doing webscraping ( i used pd.read_excel to make the question more simple), I have to have it in the loop to go through the [i]

Comment: Regardless of what you try to read, it still doesn't change that initial `pd.DataFrame` must be assigned outside the loop. You are merging `data_df` to `new_df` but `new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=new_column)` is replacing merged df with new, empty (only header) dataframe.

Comment: I understand that, but reading or getting information itself is a looping process. While loop is needed for scraping the info too.